# Cordova and adb-server issue

Tags: android, cordova, adb

I'm building a project with Cordova. On iOS, the workflow seems about what I was expecting but on Android it's quite the balancing act and I'm not entirely sure how to fix. Initially, I receive the following error when running `cordova run android ...`:

```
Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device unauthorized.
```

From here, I run `adb-kill server` and run `cordova run android ...` again. The emulator and application appear to launch without the previous adb issues, however, after showing the splash screen, the application crashes with the following error dialog in the Android emulator:

```
Application Error

The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
```

If I run `cordova run android ...` one more time the application loads successfully and I can run through the application as expected. If I reboot, I need to start this process all over again. This application works on other people's computers so I imagine there is something misconfigured on my system but I'm not sure the best way to proceed determining what is wrong.

Comment: Your error says "device unauthorized". Please navigate to <ANDROID_SDK_HOME>\platform-tools and execute 'adb devices' command to check whether the device is authorized. If not, re-authorize and try again

Comment: Any update on this

Comment: When I run that command I see my emulator. I don't see anything that says whether or not the device is authorized in the list

Comment: Could you try adding this preference in you config.xml under android platform: <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" /> ideally means increasing the timeout value to 20 seconds

Comment: @Gandhi thank you for this suggestion. I made it 700000 previously and it still was having this issue. Is it possible my app is starting too slowly?

Comment: possible. Thats why this may be inconsistent. One more alternative it to remove and re-add the android platform once

Comment: @Gandhi I will try with an actual device instead of the emulator -- I did run Cordova remove platform android and added it back in without much success

Comment: Sure. While trying with actual device, please check for device authorization status. Also was just checking for alternative solutions and someone has suggested this "Edit your virtual device (ADV) and go into advanced settings and uncheck Multi-Core CPU." Try out your luck

Comment: also wanted to understand that are you getting both "The connection to the server was unsuccessful" and "Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete" issue in emulator only?

Comment: any update on this>

Comment: For info : I succeed to fix a similar issue thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119648/117092

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The possible solutions for this inconsistent scenario is as follows:

1. Add this preference in you config.xml under android platform:

   `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />`
2. Kill and restart adb server before every launch
3. Try creating a new AVD and mention it as target while launching the AVD
4. Remove and re-add android platform and rebuild the same

Hope it helps.

UPDATE: preference snippet added

Comment: @RyanLanciaux Hi Ryan, sorry it got missed out in the formatting

Answer (score 12):

I am facing the same problem.

Sometimes it helps to run:

```
adb kill-server
adb forward --remove-all
adb start-server
```

However, I still have to run this from time to time and it can't be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Update:

This doesn't seem to be the answer - upon some more time, I'm still receiving

```
Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device unauthorized.
```

## Original

I removed my avd device and created a new one. Additionally I updated `loadUrlTimeoutValue` to be a bit higher and everything started working.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same troubles, however do you found a workarround or solution?

Comment: Genymotion worked a lot better for me than the other Android emulators. Also starting the emulator before launching the app seemed to give me a much higher success rate (still had some trouble but not as frequent)

Answer (score 2):

You are obviously experiencing a *race condition* where `adb` device is already enumerated/connected but not yet authorized. You could either wait for `cordova` to fix their code to eliminate the race condition altogether (or maybe even do it yourself) or just use `userdebug` (or `eng`) Android image with `ro.adb.secure=0`

Answer (score 0):

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete""

Combined it all - and it worked

config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

command -

```
adb kill-server
adb forward --remove-all
adb start-server
```