# Ionic:Android Emulator Error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-3

I'm trying to test my Ionic(3.16.0) hybrid app using Android Emulator that ships with Android Studio v3.0. `/myapp> ionic cordova build android` successfully creates the build. But when I run `/myapp> ionic cordova emulate android` the emulator starts and loads the screen, however, I'm not able to locate the my app in the emulator. Also the stack trace in the terminal logs are seen below:

```
Waiting for emulator to start...

emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator:
Listening for console connections on port: 5584
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5584
Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: C:\Users\ilourdus\AppData\Local\Android\Sd
k\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

I've adb server running and the platform-tools path added to the system PATH. I've Cordova 6.5.0.

Can I get some help about the errors in the above log and how to bring up my app in the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved after I changed the CPU/ABI Image from "Google Play...(x86)" to "Google API...(x86)"

Comment: how do I do that? Why are these answers also so scarce in information?

Comment: kindly provide the complete details on where to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Restart ADB Server:
Open a command prompt or terminal and run the following commands:

-For Windows:

adb kill-server

adb start-server

-For macOS/Linux:

sudo adb kill-server

sudo adb start-server

-Then, try running your emulator again.