# Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: error for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I am getting the `getprop,dev.bootcomplete` error after building and deploying the new debug-apk file to the Android emulator through Ionic framework.

The emulator pops open to the home screen for Android but the app is not installed on the emulator and thus does not open on startup for the emulator.

I had looked at similar posts on this issue and tried the different steps in adb, deleting and creating new devices for the emulator and I have both the x86 and x86_64 images installed for the API level that I am testing in which is API 26. I am not sure of what else I can do. I don't believe that removing android from cordova and then adding it back in will solve the issue. The error log is below.

**Edit:**

Every post I have seen thus far on this issue has not resolved the issue. I still have yet to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio or any of the SDK tools, but I don't think I need to.

Something that may be causing the issue is that I had to revert my NDK version back to r16b instead of the more recent r17b because my app was not building correctly with ionic cordova. It is building correctly now but the emulator is still having this issue and wont install my app.

Error Log:

```
emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
(node:11468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: C:\Users\noaht\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device still connecting
    at C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\lib\Adb.js:88:25
    at _rejected (C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:864:24)
    at C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Noah\Noah School\SSAapp\SMAPP\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:11468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11468) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
emulator: S
aving state on exit with session uptime 4695 ms
```

Comment: Is there any solution out there that can fix this problem because the app is not installing on my emulators through Android Studio but it is installing and working on my phone?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604265/cordova-and-adb-server-issue

Comment: The answer by jcesarmobile works. He correctly states it has been fixed on only in Android 7.1.0+. I'm using **6.4.0** so the code changes in emulator.js are a fix for me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a cordova-android [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14165) because Google probably changed the error message when trying to run the app.

It has been fixed already and released in cordova-android 7.1.1 or newer. If you can't update to those versions do:

I think it would work if you apply [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/457/files) change yourself to `yourAppName/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js`

Change

`if ((error && error.message &&
            (error.message.indexOf('not found') > -1)) ||
            (error.message.indexOf('device offline') > -1))`

to

`if ((error && error.message &&
            (error.message.indexOf('not found') > -1)) ||
            (error.message.indexOf('device offline') > -1) ||
            (error.message.indexOf('device still connecting') > -1))`

Comment: I'm trying that now to see if it fixes the issue

Comment: The emulator boots a little slower but that fixed the issue, thank you so much!

Comment: This worked for me. I had a similar issue, but when I had multiple AVD installed on my machine. It worked fine when only one AVD was installed.

Comment: For anyone tired of doing this on your scripted deployments, use: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gegenokitaro/cordova-android/8d497784ac4a40a9689e616cd486c4ed07d3e063/bin/templates/cordova/lib/emulator.js -O platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js` to automate it.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm using Android 7.1.4 and I needed to add an additional new error message:  'device still authorizing'.

Answer (score 20):

Another workaround is to start emulator from Android studio and then run cordova command to run app. This way cordova finds the emulator already running and it avoids the race condition.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to try and see if that works. If it does, is there way to fix the race condition, so I don't have to have Android Studio running all the time?

Comment: Did the solution adding configuration in config.xml <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" /> worked for you? I tried that solution but it didnt workd for me. I mentioned that in my previous solution but @coldspeed edited my comment

Comment: Well I did it at value= "7000" is it better to out it at 700000? I still don't think that is going to fix the issue

Comment: Is there anything else you would suggest doing to try to fix the problem?

Comment: None at this time but if I find something will let you know.

Answer (score 7):

This was a solution for me in Ionic 3 version:

1. Open Android studio, go to AVD Manager
2. Create a new AVD device, click on "show advanced settings"
3. Select "Cold boot". By default, the "Quick boot" is selected.

Try to run emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

I was get the same error when working with the following command on my windows 10 machine,

```
cordova emulate android --target=N5Oreo
```

`Windows 10
Corodva 7.1.0 
Oreo based emulator`

the issue was fixed temporarily with the answer by jcesarmobile ([Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: error for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935337/failed-to-execute-shell-command-getprop-dev-bootcomplete-on-device-error-for/51079689#51079689))
but it kept on resurfacing.

When i execute the command, the emulator was launched but the error kept coming again and again. I restarted the machine and and then it worked for few days then it kicked in again.

I found that `adb` is a powerful tool. So instead of depending on `cordova emulate android --target=N5Oreo` to build and launch I used `cordova build android` and installed the resultant build by using `adb install myApp.apk` to the currently running emulator.