# CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete""

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, onesignal

I'm new into Ionic Framework. I am implementing the OneSignal Push notification on ionic 3.

> cli packages: (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
> Node              : v8.11.3
> npm               : 6.1.0
> OS                : Windows 7
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : C:\Sdk\tools
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Then when i execute this command.

> ionic cordova run android.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 7s 44 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 43
>   up-to-date Built the following apk(s):
>           C:/rss-test-master/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/debug/android-debug.apk

Then when the emulator appears i suddenly get this kind of error.

> (node:4824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to
>   execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error:
>   C:\Sdk\tools\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
>   Error output: error: device still connecting

After this i didn't recieved any notifications on my end.

Comment: Any recommendation for this? thanks.

Comment: Please try solution mentioned in URL [Boot issue with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935337/failed-to-execute-shell-command-getprop-dev-bootcomplete-on-device-error-for/51005353#51005353)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched a lot about this problem but the only thing that worked for me was running the emulator by starting it on the AVD Manager and later execute the cordova emulate android command. This issue is related with the installing of your app on the advice so with this way after you are executing the emulator, you install the app and it should have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running the same problem but to avoid opening the AVD manager, I run the emulate android command, then when the virtual device opens I go back to the console and press CTRL + C and re run the emulate android command again.