# CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-android

When I'm trying to run the command `ionic cordova run android` I'm getting some error in cmd as

```
audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
(node:4940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: C:\Users\hi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device still authorizing
    at D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\lib\Adb.js:88:25
    at _rejected (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:864:24)
    at D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:4940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[7104]:WARNING:android/android-emu/android/base/async/AsyncSocketServer.cpp:99:Error when accepting host connectionError message: Unknown error
UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(1002, 87), size=(272x21), dirty=(272x21 0, 0) (The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.)
```

Here emulator is poping up but the app is not avalible in the device. I have tried the method as he descried in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935337/failed-to-execute-shell-command-getprop-dev-bootcomplete-on-device-error-for) But still I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message is different from the one on my other answer, try editing the code to also add your error message.

```
if ((error && error.message &&
    (error.message.indexOf('not found') > -1)) ||
    (error.message.indexOf('device offline') > -1) ||
    (error.message.indexOf('device still connecting') > -1) ||
    (error.message.indexOf('device still authorizing') > -1))
```

Comment: yes, I've tried it but still, I get the error.
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to execute sh        ell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: C:\Users\hi\AppData\Lo        cal\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error ou        tput:
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.`

Comment: that's a different error, it's telling you the device is not authorized. Didn't it show you a prompt on the device to authorize it? Try disabling and enabling usb debugging and/or revoking the authorization so it prompts you again

Comment: No, it's not displaying on the device. I'm trying in the emulator not using usb debuging..

Comment: then make sure you don't have any device plugged to your computer, and create a new emulator as that one seems to have some problem.